# VB.NET VS2012 does not autocomplete "Public Property"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, properties, autocomplete

I do remember that an earlier version of VS autocompleted the rest of the property function when I typed something like

```
"Public Property ImagesImported() As Boolean"
```

The IDE automatically added the Setter and Getter.

However, VS2012 does not. When I press enter at the end of this line, nothing happens.
I have to type the getters and setter myself.

Did I do anything wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: it does more now - thats all you need for an "auto-property" it adds a  `_ImagesImported` backing field and assignments in the getter and setter.  If you need it manual, add "public get" and tap enter fot it to add the blocks (although the parens in your example are incorrect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an intentional design change.  What you are seeing here is an auto-implemented property.  It is a fully functional property complete with a backing field.  The VB.Net IDE prefers this form because it's complete and more succinct

If you want to get the code spit for full properties you need to drop down to the next line, type `Get` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thx. I wonder why this change was made. I loved the previous version.

Comment: @tmighty at the time we decided to embrace the new features and put them a bit more in the foreground

Comment: @tmighty, `Public Property Foo As Boolean` is all you need - its doing the getting and setting for you!

Comment: @tmighty yes, i used to work on the VB.Net team several years ago and actually worked in part on this exact feature.  Now I work on a C# derivative language

Comment: @JaredPar I am just so glad that I can go to sleep at night without twisting my mind about if a function name is the appropriate one :-) I truly believe that these are the things that keep you awake at night :-)

Comment: @tmighty one of many, i have stayde up many a night debating the name of a particular API.

Comment: @JaredPar If you have a chance to talk to somebody from the TTS team: Please tell them I have made the best sounding German Text-To-Speech system. I am still waiting to become a millionaire :-)

Comment: @tmighty nice to meet you as well :)

Comment: @JaredPar I got used to typing "Get" now, but I really wonder why one has to do so when he already type e. g. "Public WriteOnly SomeValue() As String". I mean there is only one way that the next line can be, namely "Get". Did I miss something important here?

Comment: @tmighty the line itself is a complete and valid property so it can be any other valid declaration (new property, field, method, etc ...)